PI Approximation With Arcsine Infinite Series
While Playing with numbers last night I stumbled on an approximation of pi that was quite exciting. I'm sure it has been discovered before, but it was a fun journey nevertheless and I wanted to share it.
I haven't found the approximation on the web yet, but I have seen things that resemble it, which probably means there just needs to be some algebraic adjustments and it will be a well known approximation. Please help me find it.
I was trying find the length of the sides of a triangle with $45^\circ$, $22.5^\circ$, $11.25^\circ$, etc.
$$
\sin(45^\circ) = \sin(\frac{45\pi}{180})
$$
And because I was halving the degree each step I made a function.
$$
f(x)= \sin(\frac{\frac{45\pi}{2^x}}{180})
$$
Which can be simplified to.
$$
f(x)= \sin(\frac{\pi}{2^{x+2}})
$$
At this moment I thought, oh you could use some algebra and trig to get this equation to equal $\pi$.
$$
\pi=2^{x+2}\arcsin(f(x))
$$
We know the answer to f(1) is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$.
$$
\pi=2^3\arcsin(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})
$$
We also know we can use the infinite series to remove arcsine.
$$
\pi = 8 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(2n)!}{ 4^n(n!)^2(2n+1) })(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})^{2n+1}
$$
I then did the next x in the f(x), f(2), and it gave me a faster convergence.
$$
\pi = 16 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(2n)!}{ 4^n(n!)^2(2n+1) })(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}})^{2n+1}
$$
I then noticed the pattern and this continues to make the convergence on $\pi$ faster as you increase x in f(x).
$$
\pi = 32 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(2n)!}{ 4^n(n!)^2(2n+1) })(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}})^{2n+1}
$$
If any of you know where I can read more about this, I would really enjoy it. I hope you found this as entertaining as I did. Happy Mathing ;)

I liked your method and I'm interested to learn about it too. But sadly everyone somehow ignored your question :( Wish someone could help us know better

I hope somebody finds it that knows much more than I do about this topic.

Isn't your observation just the result of the $\sin^{-1}(x)$ series converging more rapidly as $x\to 0$?

I suppose I was wondering more about whether or not this is a known series to approximate pi.

I just found this, it doesn't have the infinite series to converge beyond the step 0 in my example. But it was fun to see similar trains of thought.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula
